# The reason why the output of ZCS-controlled boost converter is 1.2V,not 1V in this paper

Tags: voltage, boost, charge, shunt

Here is the three stage  stepping up architecture,and in the paper,the author said that when \$ V_{out} \$ increase up to 1V,shunt connecting the capacitors  \$ C_{DDi} \$and \$ C_{out} ...Finally,the ZCS-controlled boost converter is gated and regulated by the on-chip reference circuitry, providing a 1.2-V regulated voltage at the output .

My question is when \$ V_{out} \$ up to 1V,\$ C_{DDi} \$and \$ C_{out} \$ will be shunt connected,then,why will the \$ V_{out} \$ = 1.2V in the end,not 1V?

Also,i want to make sure something,for the 1. mark in the first picture,it said  the internal voltage \$ V_{DDi} \$ is boosted with an enhanced charging current into  \$ C_{DDi} \$.Dose it mean that the \$ C_{DDi} \$ charge to boost the \$ V_{DDi} \$?

[image]
[image]

This paper is from the :ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6484920/

Comment: "why will the Vout = 1.2V in the end" - why wouldn't it?

Comment: Why will the Vout = 1.2V,but not 1V ? The author said when Vout =1V,it will shunt connect that two capacitor,so does that two capacitor discharge and let the Vout become from 1V to 1.2V?

Comment: The paper says that when the ZCS booster is activated it produces 1.2V at Vout. Since CDDi is 'shorted' to Cout, that means Vddi should also be 1.2V.

Comment: Oh!I misunderstand the meaning,now i get it

Comment: By the way.The paper said the internal voltage \$ V_{DDi} \$ is boosted with an enhanced charging current into  \$ C_{DDi} \$.Dose it mean that the \$ C_{DDi} \$ charge to boost the \$ V_{DDi} \$?or discharge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when Vout up to 1V,CDDi and Cout will be shunt connected,then,why will
>   the Vout = 1.2V in the end,not 1V?

Vout is 1.2V because the ZCS controlled converter boosts the TEG voltage and regulates it at 1.2V, and when the shunt is turned on V<sub>DDI</sub> also becomes 1.2V.

> it said the internal voltage VDDi is boosted with an enhanced charging
>   current into CDDi. Does it mean that the CDDi charge to boost the VDDi?

Yes. The voltage on C<sub>DDI</sub> is first boosted to 300mV by the Low-Voltage Starter. This is sufficient to operate the logic circuit, which then activates the Auxiliary Step-up Converter to boost the voltage to 800mV. At this point the ZCS-Controlled Boost Converter is activated, which charges C<sub>OUT</sub> while the logic circuits are still being powered by the Auxiliary Step-up Converter. During this time C<sub>OUT</sub> is isolated from C<sub>DDI</sub> so it can charge up without dragging down V<sub>DDI</sub>.

When the voltage on C<sub>OUT</sub> gets high enough to power the entire circuit the 'shunt' is turned on, connecting V<sub>OUT</sub> to V<sub>DDI</sub> so the logic circuit gets 1.2V. The Auxiliary Step-up Converter is now no longer required so it can be turned off. The Low-Voltage Starter also turns off because the extra load of the ZCS-Controlled Boost Converter causes the TEG's output voltage to drop below the Low-Voltage Starter's operating voltage.

This 3 stage stepping up procedure is required because the TEG cannot produce enough voltage to run the ZCS-Controlled Boost Converter (or even the Auxiliary Step-up Converter) directly. However when lightly loaded it *can* produce sufficient voltage to operate the Low-Voltage Starter, which can only produce enough voltage to operate the Auxiliary Step-up Converter. Once the Step-up or Boost Converter gets going it can use its own output voltage to power its control circuit, making the previous stage redundant.